# Can I have a layer in my map that gets its imagery from say google? (ArcGIS Mobile 10)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-mobile

I've been messing with ArcGIS Mobile and I get that it loads and caches layers from an ArcGIS Server for disconnected use. I'm wondering if it supports layers where data is loaded from a layer in realtime? I can't find any examples where I create a layer, give it a URL and have it load imagery data as I pan the map.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has had no answers or comments in the 18 months since being asked and its asker has not logged into this site during that time.

Comment: @PolyGeo That only means it's old: lack of activity is hardly a relevant criterion to determine whether a thread may be on topic.

Comment: @whuber I agree - "off topic" was poor choice of wording inserted by the only close choice that offered free format reason - question clearly is on-topic so I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/windows-mobile/app/index.html#//007v00000038000000), the answer is yes you can use Google or Bing basemaps in ArcGIS for Windows Mobile.  You can also use ArcGIS Online free of charge if you don't have your own ArcGIS Map Server.